# Python-twitter api.VerifyCredentials() returns none

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I am using python-twitter api and i got consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret but when i try code below i got this output {} for `print api.VerifyCredentials()` and i got none for `print status.text`

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='**',
                      consumer_secret='**',
                      access_token_key='**',
                      access_token_secret='**')

print api.VerifyCredentials() #returns {}
status = api.PostUpdate('Ilovepython-twitter!')
print status.text #returns none
```

What do you think is problem here?

Comment: i used tweepy instead. problem is about python-twitter api i think.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and switched to Tweepy as well, seemed just as easy and was able to do the same basic functions.

Comment: switching to tweepy works, I suggest Burk should put it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem was library 'twitter' for sure. Don't import 'twitter' use 'tweepy' instead and it will work.